# Elasticsearch Java API : Aggregation Filter for document counts

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api, elasticsearch-aggregation

I want to implement an aggregation that only returns the documents whose frequency is above a certain threshold.

For instance, here is the aggregation to get all of the documents with their counts

```
AggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders
                .terms("agg").field("column_name");
```

so this gives me the counts of documents for each value in `column_name`

```
[{"doc_count":30,"key":"val1"},{"doc_count":29,"key":"val2"},{"doc_count":23,"key":"val3"}]
```

now, lets say i dont want all of these documents. I only want those that have a `doc_count` greater than `25`

So the ideal result would be

`[{"doc_count":30,"key":"val1"},{"doc_count":29,"key":"val2"}]`

how do i apply such a filter to my aggregation? I was looking at `FilterBuilders` and filter aggregations, but they are for applying filters on any values within the documents. For instance i can apply a filter to only get the documents where `val1 == xza` for `column_name`

but that is not what i am looking for. I want to apply a threshold for the `doc_cunt` values after the aggregation has been applied.

Is this possible? I am using elasticsearch java api version 1.7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terms aggregation has a built in option called `min_doc_count`. See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count_3) for their documentation on it. I haven't used Java API, but [this example](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=camunda-bpm-elasticsearch-master/elasticsearch-cockpit-plugin/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/cockpit/plugin/dashboards/resources/ProcessInstanceHistogramResource.java) seems to use `.minDocCount()` in an example (ctrl-f 'minDocCount')